# Где в Java хранить разные типы данных и чтобы обращаться к ним через строку?

Tags: java

Где(в чём) хранить разные типы данных и чтобы обращаться к ним через строку, пример:

```
arr["дом"][kvartir]=12
```

или как то классом

Comment: «Обращаться через строку» это видимо HashMap, а разные типы-то зачем?

Comment: С помощью квадратных скобок можно обращаться только к элементам массива и только по индексу.

Comment: Хранение разных типов данных (не имеющих логически общего родительского интерфейса) в коллекции является антипаттерном. В частности, вот пример коллекции, который удовретворяет вашим ожиданиям: `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`.